# Taking Screenshot with Texture2D.Readpixels on Oculus Device Results in Blank Image

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I try to take a screenshot on Oculus devices using Unity C# Script. But the result only shows a black or white image. I think read pixel is not working correctly. Can anyone help with the solution?

```
    public void PressedButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshotAndShare());
    }
    private IEnumerator TakeScreenshotAndShare()
    {
     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
      Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
      ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, 1000, 600), 0, 0);
      ss.Apply();
      var store = ss;
       string myFileName = "Screenshot" + System.DateTime.Now.Hour + System.DateTime.Now.Minute +                  System.DateTime.Now.Second + ".png";
      string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath+"/ "+ myFileName);
      File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, ss.EncodeToPNG());
      Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath + "path"); 
    }
```

[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5nbp.png)

Comment: Have you tried [`ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html)?

Comment: Not Working in 2021 version